# Java loop until user enters a value of 0. The values must be between 1-4 and if over 4, ask user to try inputting again

Tags: java, while-loop, average

I need to create a loop where the user can input any amount of numbers between 1-4 and then I calculate the average. Typing 0 will end the program and calculate the average. Any value greater than 4 or less than 0 should not count and ask the user to input the value again. I'm stuck on the last part. I'm not sure if the while loop is the correct loop to use either. Thanks for any help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sum = 0;
    double count = 0;

    while(input.hasNextInt()) {
        int num = input.nextInt();
        if (num == 0)
            break;
        if (num > 4)
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
        sum += num;
        count += 1;
    }

    System.out.println("Average: " + sum/count);
}
```

Comment: you are always adding the `num` to the `sum` if the input isn't 0.

Comment: What if num is negative?

Comment: suggest changing your conditional and only adding if `num` is valid

Comment: When `num > 4`, then `continue` to go back to the top of the loop.  Also, consider always adding { } to an `if` statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will always hit the lines:

```
sum += num;
count += 1;
```

Because the code just drops through from the second if statement.

The following would work - note the else if and else blocks will only be executed when the first if drops through:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sum = 0;
    double count = 0;

    while(input.hasNextInt()) {
        int num = input.nextInt();

        if (num == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else if (num > 4) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
        }
        else {
            sum += num;
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Average: " + sum/count);
}
```

Comment: I would add further validation to the `else if` to make sure that the number is between 0 and 4. Also, include an explanation for why you added the `else if` block rather than saying that it may be better with it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I just tried it out in my code and I understand what's happening but the console says there is an error in the break because it can't be used outside the loop or switch. It is in the brackets so i'm a little confused.

Comment: I don't see the error. Perhaps you've got a bit mixed up with opening and closing braces. I've added a full code snippet to my answer now, see if that works